# How can I skip the first line of a file in Go?

Tags: go

How can I read a file in Go and skip the first line / headers?

In Python I know I could do

```
counter = 0
with open("my_file_path", "r") as fo:
    try:
        next(fo)
    except:
        pass
    for _ in fo:
         counter = counter + 1
```

This is my Go application

```
package main    
import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "os"
)

func readFile(fileLocation string) int {
    fileOpen, _ := os.Open(fileLocation)
    defer fileOpen.Close()
    fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(fileOpen)

    counter := 0
    for fileScanner.Scan() {
        //fmt.Println(fileScanner.Text())
        counter = counter + 1
    }

    return counter
}

func main() {
    fileLocation := flag.String("file_location", "default value", "file path to count lines")
    flag.Parse()

    counted := readFile(*fileLocation)
    println(counted)
}
```

I will be reading a huge file and don't want to be evaluating each line if the index is 0.

Answer (score 8):

How about to move to the next token before the loop

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
scanner.Scan() // this moves to the next token
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}
```

file

```
1
2
3
```

output

```
2
3
```

https://play.golang.org/p/I2w50zFdcg0

Comment: This is the way, just move scanner to the second line before looping.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func readFile(filename string) (int, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    count := 0
    s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    if s.Scan() {
        for s.Scan() {
            count++
        }
    }
    if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return count, nil
}

func main() {
    filename := `test.file`

    count, err := readFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(count)
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat test.file
1234567890
abc
$ go run count.go
1
$
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this

```
func readFile(fileLocation string) int {
            fileOpen, _ := os.Open(fileLocation)
            defer fileOpen.Close()
            fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(fileOpen)
            counter := 0
            for fileScanner.Scan() {
                // read first line and ignore
                fileScanner.Text()
                break
            }

           for fileScanner.Scan() {
                // read remaining lines and process
                txt := fileScanner.Text()
                counter = counter + 1
               // do something with text
            }


            return counter
        }
```

Edit:

```
func readFile(fileLocation string) int {
            fileOpen, _ := os.Open(fileLocation)
            defer fileOpen.Close()
            fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(fileOpen)
            counter := 0
            if fileScanner.Scan() {
                // read first line and ignore
                fileScanner.Text()
            }

           for fileScanner.Scan() {
                // read remaining lines and process
                txt := fileScanner.Text()
               // do something with text
               counter = counter + 1
            }


            return counter
        }
```

Comment: is my first time using goland, but why do we need to first loop?  can we just use fileScanner.Text() and second loop?

Comment: Have made an edit. Had missed break statement in the first loop. Well the point is to read the first line if it exists and ignore it. You can do it using a normal if block also

Comment: Why do you have a loop if you break unconditionally after the first iteration :-S